# Check if an object in an array is exist in another array, then change the value of that another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have an array A

```
const arrayA = [
          {
            id:a,
            check:false
          },
          {
            id:b,
            check:false
          },
          {
            id:c,
            check:false
          }
```

and an array B

```
const arrayB = [
  {
    id:a,
  },
  {
    id:b,  
  }
]
```

and i want to check if arrayB is exist arrayA by id, then change check to true. Using lodash or js array methods

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly but this is the solution I came up with.

```
arrayA.map((item) => ({ ...item, check: arrayB.some(({ id: idB }) => item.id === idB ) }))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested `forEach` loops, and check, if `id` matches then set `check` to true.

```js
const arrayA = [{
    id: "a",
    check: false
  },
  {
    id: "b",
    check: false
  },
  {
    id: "c",
    check: false
  }
]

const arrayB = [{
    id: "a",
  },
  {
    id: "b",
  }
]

arrayB.forEach((b)=>{
  arrayA.forEach((a)=>{
   if(b.id == a.id){
    a.check = true;
   }
  })
})

console.log(arrayA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array containing the ids of `arrayB` and then check the objects in `arrayA` like

```js
const arrayA = [
          {
            id: 'a',
            check:false
          },
          {
            id:'b',
            check:false
          },
          {
            id:'c',
            check:false
          } ];
          
const arrayB = [
  {
    id:'a',
  },
  {
    id:'b',  
  }
];

const idsB = arrayB.map( obj => obj.id);
arrayA.forEach(obj => { if(idsB.indexOf(obj.id) > -1) obj.checked = true; } );
arrayA.forEach(obj => {console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with this, which is not different than double loop, but may read easier.

```
arrayA.map((a) => {
    a.check = arrayB.findIndex((b) => b.id === a.id) != -1;
    return a;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it may help you**

```js
const arrayA = [
  {id:'a',check:false},
  {id:'b',check:false},
  {id:'c',check:false}
]
const arrayB = [
  {id:'a',},
  {id:'b',}
]

arrayB.map(i => {
   return i.check = arrayA.find(item => i.id == item.id)?.check;
});

console.log(arrayB)
```